# npgsql.msi + GAC silent installation

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

we need to install npgsql with the GAC option, on several computers, by using the MSI.
By default GAC is not enabled so i m looking for a silent parameters for msiexec to activate it by default

thanks

[GAC option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCvhD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

we have the npgsql.msi and during the setup (see screenshot in my original post),we need to enable the GAC option, it's not enabled by default.

So my question is how can i enable this setting on a MSI command line, something like (but it can be anything)

```
msiexec /i npgsql.msi PROPERTY=GAC
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option ADDLOCAL=ALL

```
msiexec /i npgsql.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL
```

That selects all options for install

Best,
Matthias

Comment: great thanks a lot, it worked :) a lot of time saved, christmas gift :)